# Detecting what used bandwidth retroactively

Tags: networking, logging

I've got 2 unexplained network spikes.  They are both short duration but one of them has appeared on my private IP instead of my public IP and this was unexpected.  Both are very short duration.  Are there standard logs that would give me a clue as to WHAT did this?  Is there something I could be running to know WHAT did this?

This is an 8GB nginx, gunicorn, postgres server running ubuntu 20.04 at a commercial hosting provider.

---

```
Firewall setup:
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       A.B.C.D
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       A.B.C.E
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       A.B.C.D (v6)
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       A.B.C.E (v6)
```

[image: Network Usage Chart]

Comment: There are no standard "network" logs. Have you checked the logs of those services you mentioned in that timeframe?

Comment: Is the server is not yours and you have no direct access I would ask the company hosting the server. It could be something they are doing.